# Ignite Error : Failed to finish operation (too many remaps): 32

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am loading data from kafka to ignite data streamers in parallel in multiple ignite nodes. But when I kill one of these nodes(for checking fault tolerance), I am getting following error. Some Messages are also getting lost.

```js
        class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to finish operation (too many remaps): 32 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5.apply(DataStreamerImpl.java:863) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5.apply(DataStreamerImpl.java:828) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter$ArrayListener.apply(GridFutureAdapter.java:456) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter$ArrayListener.apply(GridFutureAdapter.java:439) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:271) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListeners(GridFutureAdapter.java:259) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:389) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:355) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:343) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$Buffer.submit(DataStreamerImpl.java:1716) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$Buffer.update(DataStreamerImpl.java:1416) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.load0(DataStreamerImpl.java:932) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addData(DataStreamerImpl.java:576) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addData(DataStreamerImpl.java:544) 
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.StreamAdapter.addMessage(StreamAdapter.java:184) 
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.KafkaStreamer.access$100(KafkaStreamer.java:47) 
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.KafkaStreamer$1.run(KafkaStreamer.java:156) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterTopologyCheckedException: Failed to send request (node has left): 0a04411f-a797-4526-826a-96c52549b0d0 
        ... 11 more 
[21:45:24] (err) Failed to execute compound future reducer: GridCompoundFuture [rdc=null, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=1, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false]]class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: DataStreamer request failed [node=f48edaa8-74df-4503-bf9b-1fdc6d642744] 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$Buffer.onResponse(DataStreamerImpl.java:1777) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$3.onMessage(DataStreamerImpl.java:335) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1215) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:843) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$2100(GridIoManager.java:108) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$6.run(GridIoManager.java:783) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please link logs. Also there was a fix in 1.8 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-500, try update your Ignite.

Comment: We are using Ignite 1.9 version and assume that above fix is available. Below is the overall details and logs.  Kafka version - 0.9, Ignite version - 1.9
1. Ignite receives data via Kafka Streamer. There are 27 Kafka partitions. We use 27 Ignite instances deployed on 3 physical nodes.
2. Tuple Extractor is implemented in ignite code 
3. All the Caches are defined as partitioned
4. We also use streamvisitor for processing the data
when we kill 1 instance (out of  27 instances) of ignite then we get the below error repeatedly on all the instances.

Comment: Where are the logs?

Comment: Hi, @ValentinKulichenko I have attached ignite logs at following link [IgniteLogs](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhlSNPET43FRagqiUWdRKD92zFg)

Comment: Is this still actual? I actually don't see 'too many remaps' error in provided log. All I see is that there is a hanged operation, probably due to deadlock (make sure batched cache operations are ordered), and them streamer is closed causing messages to be ignored.